# Scripted concatenation of strings in curl command payload

Tags: bash, shell, curl, string-concatenation

I use `curl` to test an user account creation API as follows:

```
curl -s -X POST "https://$APISERVER/users" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{ \
"username": "'$NEWUSERNAME'", \
"firstName": "'$NEWUSERFIRSTNAME'", \
"lastName": "'$NEWUSERLASTNAME'", \
"displayName": "'$NEWUSERDISPLAYNAME'", \
"password": "'$NEWUSERPASSWORD'" \
}'
```

and the variables are supplied via command line arguments:

```
APISERVER=http://localhost:8080
NEWUSERNAME=$1
NEWUSERPASSWORD=$2
NEWUSERFIRSTNAME=$3
NEWUSERLASTNAME=$4

# Calculated variable
NEWUSERDISPLAYNAME="${NEWUSERFIRSTNAME} ${NEWUSERLASTNAME}"
```

An example invocation of the script is as follows: `./test-new-user.sh jdoe Hello123 John Doe`, resulting in the following variable values:

```
NEWUSERNAME=jdoe
NEWUSERPASSWORD=Hello123
NEWUSERFIRSTNAME=John
NEWUSERLASTNAME=Doe
```

*(I intended `NEWUSERDISPLAYNAME` to be set to "John Doe")*

But I get back an exception from the server, because the payload in the `curl` command appears to be cut-off, incomplete or malformed.

```
JSON parse error: Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: 
java.io.PushbackInputStream@2eda6052; line: 1, column: 293]; nested 
exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Unexpected end-of-input in VALUE_STRING\n at [Source: 
java.io.PushbackInputStream@2eda6052; line: 1, column: 293]\n at 
[Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2eda6052; line: 1, column: 142] 
(through reference chain: 
com.mycompany.api.pojos.NewUser[\"displayName\"])"
```

If I hard code value for `displayName` in the above curl command (as below), the user creation request goes through and works perfectly.

```
"displayName": "John Doe", \
```

I suspect it has to do with the space in `displayName` and how I insert the value for `displayName` using `"'$NEWUSERDISPLAYNAME'"`. Is there a safe way to perform variable substitution in the `curl` command's POST request payload?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to quote shell variables:

```
curl -s -X POST "https://$APISERVER/users" \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{ \
"username": "'"$NEWUSERNAME"'", \
"firstName": "'"$NEWUSERFIRSTNAME"'", \
"lastName": "'"$NEWUSERLASTNAME"'", \
"displayName": "'"$NEWUSERDISPLAYNAME"'", \
"password": "'"$NEWUSERPASSWORD"'" \
}'
```

In order to avoid excessive quoting, try this `printf`:

```
printf -v json -- '{ "username": "%s", "firstName": "%s", "lastName": "%s", "displayName": "%s", "password": "%s" }' \
"$NEWUSERNAME" "$NEWUSERFIRSTNAME" "$NEWUSERLASTNAME" "$NEWUSERDISPLAYNAME" "$NEWUSERPASSWORD"

curl -s -X POST "https://$APISERVER/users" \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d "$json"
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks! All the other variables substitute just fine though. It is just this one which has a space in the value. Is there a better way to do this, or use curly braces notation, to make it more readable? Because the use of double-single-double quote wrapping is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

just use

$(echo $varname)

works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).